# Push data to dataLayer on Webform Ajax submit

Tags: ajax, webforms

I'm using the [Webform Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) module to ajaxify my Webform and I need to push some data to the dataLayer to use with Google Tag Manager after a successful submit.

Like:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'Submitted',
  'page': 'Contact'
});
```

Is there a simple way of doing that?

Comment: Any luck with this one ?

Comment: Yes and no. I managed to get it working but had to hack the module.
I modified the webform_ajax.js file:

`if ($wrapper.length) {
if (wrapper_id == 'webform-ajax-wrapper-your-id-here'') {
          jQuery('body').trigger('eventYouAreListeningFor');
        }`
This triggers an event and I'm able to push the data in an external file. You could also send the wrapper_id in the trigger:  `jQuery('body').trigger('eventYouAreListeningFor', [wrapper_id]);`